# Efficient way to add Components to Java Swing panel

Tags: java, performance, swing

I have a pre-constructed java panel that has about 30000 labels already added to it. I need to efficiently add this to a scrollpane on my Jframe. However if I call the add method it can take about 30 seconds to add to the scrollpane. Is there another way I can do this more efficiently? I need the UI to update quickly and if I re-add the labels to the panel everytime I need to display them I think this will be more expensive than simply loading the already rendered panel.

Comment: Have you considered using a JTable instead?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but if you have that many labels, you may want to consider creating a custom component that just directly draws all ~30k text strings in the appropriate locations.

Comment: `30000`! Did you create the labels one by one or used arrays? And why you need three thousand labels?

Comment: You should be really using an appropriate component. JTable, JList or JTree, whichever suits the situation best.

Comment: The labels have a special layout on the panel and so I don't think a Jtable would work for this. I can create a special component for but all the labels have an action listener attached and the text is coloured differently so i'm not sure if I can accomplish this? It isn't always that many labels but it just takes too long in the worst case

Comment: @user2683465 If you have a special layout, then that's probably what's causing your problem. Use a profiler to see where the most time is being spent during that 30 seconds. There are a number of tutorials on the Internet to show you how to profile code with your favorite IDE. My guess is that this will show the layout code taking up the most time as the scroll pane tries to redo the layout for the inner panel.

Comment: If you can't use `JTable` or `JList`, use the flyweight pattern to render _visible_ labels.

Comment: @trashgod Somebody actually deemed that a pattern and named it? What's next, the "local variable pattern"? I've been building up evidence to support an article I've been meaning to write titled "The Pattern Anti-Pattern". Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JasonC: `JTable` uses the [_flyweight pattern_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to apply [renderers & editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to visible cells. I didn't mean to conflated the two. See also [*Christmas Tree Applications: How to Create Frequently-Updated* `JTables` *that Perform Well*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/christmastree-138396.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rethink your design. 30000 labels looks like way too much.

Look at [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) or rethink idea if you can't decrease amount of labels.